# PCL.Storage, OpenAsync() not writing data

Tags: c#, xamarin, stream, portable-class-library

I'm trying to save a file to cache (in Xamarin.Android). When the method below is called, The input variables contain all the right data. It also finishes without errors, but when I go to read the file, it's empty (the size is correct, but it contains all 0's).

```
public async Task<bool> SaveCache(Stream data, string id)
{
    try
    {
        //cache folder in local storage
        IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        var folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Cache",
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        //save cached data
        IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(id + ".png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[data.Length];
        data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        using (Stream stream = await file.OpenAsync(PCLStorage.FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've also read the `OpenAsync()` method from the PCL.Storage library on GitHub, but the method is pretty easy, and it does do what I expect it to do...

Am I doing something wrong, or do you guys have suggestions on what's actually happening?

Comment: Have you check that the call to `data.Read()` actually reads the correct data into the `buffer` array? Have you checked the result of call to `data.Read()` and made sure it is not returning `0`? A possible cause for this might be that the `data` stream is at the end of the underlying data, thus calling `data.Read()` basically does nothing and so you're writing an empty array to the `stream`.

Comment: It's indeed the buffer which is the problem, I completely looked over that... But isn't the offset the starting point, from there it reads until data.Length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Stream.Read()` method always starts reading from the current position of the stream ([see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx)), you should ensure that you're at the correct position before trying to read anything.

In your case it seems like the `data` Stream (that is provided as parameter), is already at the end of the underlying data, so calling `Stream.Read()` will basically do nothing.

To fix this you simply need to seek the stream back to the start of its data before you're trying to read the stream contents, for example using the [Stream.Seek() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx). So your fixed code could for example look something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> SaveCache(Stream data, string id)
{
    try
    {
        //cache folder in local storage
        IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        var folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Cache",
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        //save cached data
        IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(id + ".png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[data.Length];

        //make sure stream is at beginning of data, then read data into buffer
        data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        using (Stream stream = await file.OpenAsync(PCLStorage.FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the solution for this question, thank you very much... However I didn't expect it to fill it with different date, probably has to do with encoding?

Comment: Also, the buffer Is still not written in the stream... It's still mpety...

Comment: Nothing was filled in the first place, and it has nothing to do with encoding either: When you initialize an array all it's items are set to the default value for the type of items, so when you create your `buffer` array it will at first contain only 0's as the default value of `byte` is 0. (And since no data was actually read it just stayed like that)

Comment: And for the data not being written: Can you provide a little bit more information about that? How exactly did you test that? I'm currently not able to reproduce this here on my side (testing with `MemoryStream`'s since I don't know what that `PCLStorage` thing is). Could you update your question with your current code, indicating the new problem? Or even better could you try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this?

Comment: We ended up rewriting a lot of code. I was downloading an image file, compressed that to make it smaller (into a stream), that stream needed to be saved into cache... I now just download the raw data and put in it cache right away (so the method takes a byte array now instead of the stream). The image has to be compressed before download anyway since it's a mobile app, so we're going to handle the compression on the server, that's way better than fiddling around with it on a mobile device...